# Python Bitflow Framegrabber BfUtils.BFGTLDevice Claxon-CXP1 getNode DeviceTemperature

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m attempting to acquire the temperature value from a Claxon-CXP1 connected to a Basler VNIR hyperspectral camera .

I’m following these documents and either not opening the board and or getting a null node result when I expect a value.
https://www.bitflow.com/PythonHelp/_generate/BFModule.BFGTLUtils.BFGTLDevice.html#BFModule.BFGTLUtils.BFGTLDevice
https://www.bitflow.com/PythonHelp/_generate/BFModule.BFGTLUtils.BFGTLDevice.html#BFModule.BFGTLUtils.BFGTLDevice.Open
https://www.bitflow.com/PythonHelp/_generate/BFModule.BFGTLUtils.BFGTLDevice.html#BFModule.BFGTLUtils.BFGTLDevice.getNode

Cameras and frame grabbers are powered up, operational, and produce data via other applications. I’m just not sure exactly how to get the temperature. This code was run in isolation without any other apps/drivers running.

<strike>Why is the board not opening?</strike>Edited:It was my code, forgot to check isopen again.

Why is the temp node invalid and null?

Guidance, docs, and code examples would be appreciated.

```
import typing
import time
import os
import sys

# Specify DLL file locations for import of BitFlow and CameraLink libraries
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\BitFlow SDK 6.5\Bin64")
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Program Files\CameraLink\Serial")

import BFModule.BFGTLUtils as BfUtils  # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module, wrong-import-order

def get_vnir_temp()->None:
    """_summary_
    https://www.bitflow.com/PythonHelp/_generate/BFModule.BFGTLUtils.BFGTLDevice.html#BFModule.BFGTLUtils.BFGTLDevice
    Returns:
        typing.Optional[float]: _description_
    """
    device = BfUtils.BFGTLDevice()
    print(f'bordCount: {device.boardCount()}')
    is_open = device.isOpen()
    print(f'isOpen:{is_open}')
    if is_open is not True:
        print('opening device')
        device.Open(1)
        is_open = device.isOpen()
        print(f'isOpen:{is_open}')
        time.sleep(.5)
    try:
        temp_node = device.getNode('DeviceTemperature')
        print(f'NodeName:{temp_node.DisplayName}')
        print(f'Valid:{temp_node.Valid}')
        print(f'IsNull:{temp_node.isNull}')
    except Exception:
            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
            print(f"Exception caught: {exc_type}")
            print(f"   \\__ file: {fname}, line #{exc_tb.tb_lineno}")

get_vnir_temp()

"""
output:
Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
bordCount: 0
isOpen:0
opening device
isOpen:0
NodeName:Device Temperature
Valid:False
IsNull:True
"""
```

Comment: @jdweng thanks for helping with my previous bitflow question, just tagging you here, in case you have any ideas. Thx!

Comment: FYI: I received a response from  bitflow support and they are fixing a bug with the valid and is null hydration on their side, so that is most likely the answer. I still don't see a property for the actual value on the base object and suspect I may need to cast it to get the value. I'll know when the issue is fixed on their side. Thx!